# is it possible to declare a Java Class variable using getClass()?

Tags: java, reflection, instance-variables, getter-setter

All of the relevant classes in my application instantiate a version of the class `Logger` as `logger = new Logger()`. Any class can invoke it's instance of `logger.setText(String text)`.

The `writeText(Object parameter)` method in `ClassA` is built to get the previously set string from each class instance of `logger` by invoking it's instance of `logger.getText()`.

Currently I've placed a conditional inside `wrtieText` for each of the classes.  This works, but can become an issue if I end up adding more classes.  I want a catch-all `writeText` method to accommodate for any new classes that may be added.

The following is the currently working model.  Beneath this, I have included the alternate version of `ClassA`, which attempts to do what I'm describing by using the getClass() method.

**ClassA.java**

```
public class ClassA {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ClassA classA = new ClassA();
      classA.execute();
   }

   public void execute() {
     ClassB doSomething = new ClassB();
     writeText(doSomething);

     ClassC doSomethingElse = new ClassC();
     writeText(doSomethingElse);
   }

   public void writeText(Object parameter) {
      if(parameter instanceof ClassB) {
         ClassB x = (ClassB) parameter;
         System.out.println(x.logger.getText() + "\n\n");
      }

      if(parameter instanceof ClassC) {
          ClassC x = (ClassC) parameter;
          System.out.println(x.logger.getText() + "\n\n");
      }

      if(parameter instanceof ClassD) {
          ClassD x = (ClassD) parameter;
          System.out.println(x.logger.getText() + "\n\n");
      }
   }
}
```

**Logger.java**

```
public class Logger {
   private String text = "";

   public void setText(String text) {
      this.text = text;
   }

   public String getText() {
      return this.text;
   }
}
```

**ClassB.java**

```
public class ClassB {
   Logger logger = new Logger();

   public ClassB() {          
      logger.setText("Hello from ClassB!");
   }
}
```

**ClassC.java**

```
public class ClassC {
   Logger logger = new Logger();

   public ClassC() {
      logger.setText("Hello from ClassC!");
   }
}
```

I'm trying to invoke the `getClass()` method in order to account for any class  with the following, but it's running into some problems.

**ClassA.java**

```
public class ClassA {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ClassA classA = new ClassA();
      classA.execute();
   }

   public void execute() {
     ClassB doSomething = new ClassB();
     writeText(doSomething);

     ClassC doSomethingElse = new Class();
     writeText(doSomethingElse);
   }

   public void writeText(Object parameter) {
      Class aClass = parameter.getClass();

      // now what? The following doesn't work as expected
      aClass x = (aClass) parameter;
      System.out.println(x.logger.getText());   
   }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read about the [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I already have.  That is where I got the idea for the use of getClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do it with reflection. You might iterate the fields and then call your method on a `Logger` field. Something like,

```
public void writeText(Object parameter) {
    Class<?> aClass = parameter.getClass();
    for (Field f : aClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (f.getName().equals("logger")) {
            try {
                f.setAccessible(true);
                Logger log = (Logger) f.get(parameter);
                System.out.println(log.getText());  
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, what you are trying to do will not work. Variable types need to be declared with a known type at compile time.

Use proper encapsulation.

Define an interface `HasLogger` (or whatever name fits best) which defines a method `getLogger` that returns a `Logger` value. Make your classes `ClassA`, `ClassB`, etc. implement this interface.

Change your `writeText` method to accept an argument of type `Loggable` and then just get the `Logger`

```
public void writeText(HasLogger parameter) {
    System.out.println(parameter.getLogger().getText());   
}
```